# Utilizing ipfraking to apply post-stratification weights for a Community Based Survey in Stata

Tags: sampling, stata, survey, survey-weights

I am a community data analyst for a small non-profit in South Florida. We are cleaning and preparing a local community survey for analysis and need to apply post-stratification weights to the survey to ensure it is representative. I want to utilize the Stata code [`ipfraking`](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0323), but am having some difficulty understanding exactly what is needed and ensuring I have properly created the matrices needed for comparison.

Here is some pertinent information:

1. **Description of Sampling Design**: the survey was collected over 6-9 months with a target sample size of 2970 respondents (Power=95%). These target sample was to be collected in 13 geographic clusters representing neighborhoods throughout the county with 12 clusters needing 220 respondents and 1 cluster needing 330 as an over sample (generally underrepresented part of the county by race, ethnicity, and income). All surveys were collected via an online survey format.
2. **Description of Cluster Weights**: The organization that collected the surveys did not pay particular attention to these by cluster sample sizes. Some were grossly over-sampled and others under-sampled. So, I am applying a corrective `Cluster_Wt` (desired survey proportion by cluster/actual survey proportion by cluster). The original design weight would be the 220 = 1 and 330 = 1.5 for those clusters, I suppose)

**EDITED MATERIAL: The "clusters" I describe are stratifications of the entire county, so not a sub-sample of the population (80 strata and chose 13 clusters), but a full stratification of the county into "neighborhoods".**

```
    . summarize Cluster_Wt

        Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
    -------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      Cluster_Wt |      3,639    1.218532    .5038819   .3835682   2.560317

    . codebook Cluster_Wt
    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

              type:  numeric (double)

             range:  [.38356816,2.5603175]        units:  1.000e-08
     unique values:  12                       missing .:  0/3,639

              mean:   1.21853
          std. dev:   .503882

       percentiles:        10%       25%       50%       75%       90%
                       .640651         1   1.10121   1.33499   1.94279
```

3. **Calibration Variables**: I would like to calibrate based upon 5 demographic variables: Gender, Age, Ethnicity, Education Level, and Annual Household Income.Gender is categorized as 1=Male, 2=Female; Age if Ordinal 1-5; Ethnicity is 1=Hispanic, 0=non-Hispanic; education level and annual hhi are ordinal from lowest education to highest, and lowest hhi to highest. All categories match US Census categories found in Table S0501 (https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/17_5YR/S0501/0500000US12086) and DP05 (https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/17_5YR/S0501/0500000US12086).

**EDITED: I will label weighting variables for clarity in my dataset.**

```
   codebook ethnicity gender age edu hhi
```

---

### ethnicity                                                                                            (unlabeled)

```
              type:  numeric (float)
             label:  ethlbl

             range:  [0,1]                        units:  1
     unique values:  2                        missing .:  0/3,573

        tabulation:  Freq.   Numeric  Label
                     1,660         0  Not Hispanic
                     1,913         1  Hispanic
```

---

### gender                                                                                               (unlabeled)

```
              type:  numeric (float)
             label:  genlbl

             range:  [1,2]                        units:  1
     unique values:  2                        missing .:  0/3,573

        tabulation:  Freq.   Numeric  Label
                       920         1  Male
                     2,653         2  Female
```

---

### age                                                                                                  (unlabeled)

```
              type:  numeric (float)
             label:  agelbl

             range:  [1,5]                        units:  1
     unique values:  5                        missing .:  0/3,573

        tabulation:  Freq.   Numeric  Label
                       348         1  18-24
                     1,470         2  25-44
                       724         3  45-54
                       642         4  55-64
                       389         5  65+
```

---

### edu                                                                                                  (unlabeled)

```
              type:  numeric (float)
             label:  edulbl

             range:  [1,5]                        units:  1
     unique values:  5                        missing .:  0/3,573

        tabulation:  Freq.   Numeric  Label
                       127         1  Less than High School
                       279         2  High School Graduate/GED
                     1,063         3  Some College/Vocational or
                                      Technical School/Associate's
                                      Degree
                       925         4  Bachelor's Degree
                     1,179         5  Graduate/Professional Degree
```

---

### hhi                                                                                                  (unlabeled)

```
              type:  numeric (float)
             label:  hhilbl

             range:  [1,10]                       units:  1
     unique values:  10                       missing .:  0/3,573

          examples:  4     $25,000-$34,999
                     5     $35,000-$49,999
                     6     $50,000-$74,999
                     8     $100,000-$149,999
```

--> SO YOU CAN SEE THE FULL hhi VAR -->

```
tab hhi

              hhi |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------------+-----------------------------------
         <$10,000 |        297        8.31        8.31
  $10,000-$14,999 |        144        4.03       12.34
  $15,000-$24,999 |        224        6.27       18.61
  $25,000-$34,999 |        363       10.16       28.77
  $35,000-$49,999 |        525       14.69       43.46
  $50,000-$74,999 |        590       16.51       59.98
  $75,000-$99,999 |        439       12.29       72.26
$100,000-$149,999 |        498       13.94       86.20
$150,000-$199,999 |        244        6.83       93.03
        $200,000+ |        249        6.97      100.00
------------------+-----------------------------------
            Total |      3,573      100.00
```

4. **Familiarity with Census Sources**: I understand that I would need to use the Census data for weighting. I am very familiar with US Census sources and utilize them regularly. I have included in #3 the sources for the comparison data (DP05 and S0501).

**EDITED: I pulled the census data from FactFinder (https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml); as the comments point out, this doesn't represent the 18+ population but the entire population, whereas my survey is for 18+.**

5. This survey applies to Miami-Dade County, FL. So all comparison statistics are at the county-level. The only constraints on subpop data relates to Race: the organization who developed and administered this survey allowed for multiple answers to race without adding a multiracial option, and the Gender variable was originally categorized as Male, Female, Other, but I have not found "Other" comparison groups in census data. There were a total of 19 individuals who answered Other.
6. I have attempted to utilize ipfraking on this project, but have come up with errors each time. Most recently, this is what I received.

   ```
    ipfraking [pw=Cluster_Wt], gen(rake_wt) ctotal(Census_2017_ethn Census_2017_gend Census_2017_edu Census_2017_age Census_2017_HHI)

    Warning: 47 missing values of ethnicity encountered; convergence will be impaired
    Warning: 66 missing values of gender encountered; convergence will be impaired
    variable education tabulating the control matrix Census_2017_edu not found
    r(111);
   ```

Thank you for your help!

Latest Attempt:

```
. ipfraking [pw=Cluster_Wt], gen(rake_wt) ctotal(Census_2017_ethn Census_2017_gend Census_2017_edu Census_2017_age Census_2017_HHI)

Warning: the totals of the control matrices are different:
   Target 1 (Census_2017_ethn) total         =              2702602
   Target 2 (Census_2017_gend) total         =              2702602
   Target 3 (Census_2017_edu) total          =              1906299
   Target 4 (Census_2017_age) total          =              2148568
   Target 5 (Census_2017_HHI) total          =               856572

 Iteration 1, max rel difference of raked weights = 2407.9914
 Iteration 2, max rel difference of raked weights = .75951121
 Iteration 3, max rel difference of raked weights = .2044673
 Iteration 4, max rel difference of raked weights = .07387203
 Iteration 5, max rel difference of raked weights = .02358131
 Iteration 6, max rel difference of raked weights = .00708729
 Iteration 7, max rel difference of raked weights = .00206681
 Iteration 8, max rel difference of raked weights = .00059308
 Iteration 9, max rel difference of raked weights = .00016863
 Iteration 10, max rel difference of raked weights = .00004768
 Iteration 11, max rel difference of raked weights = .00001344
 Iteration 12, max rel difference of raked weights = 3.778e-06
 Iteration 13, max rel difference of raked weights = 1.061e-06
 Iteration 14, max rel difference of raked weights = 2.977e-07
Warning: the controls Census_2017_ethn did not match
Warning: the controls Census_2017_gend did not match
Warning: the controls Census_2017_edu did not match
Warning: the controls Census_2017_age did not match
The worst relative discrepancy of  .68306 is observed for gender == 2           
Target value =    1391840; achieved value =  441134.56

   Summary of the weight changes

              |    Mean    Std. dev.    Min        Max       CV
--------------+-------------------------------------------------- 
Orig weights  |    1.221      .5055     .3836        2.56   .4141
Raked weights |    239.7      414.1       3.7        4720   1.727
Adjust factor | 192.5576               5.0317   3732.3219
```

Comment: I am the author of `ipfraking`, and I <strike>approve this message</strike> will look into this.

Comment: It would help tremendously if your weighting variables were all labeled. Otherwise it is difficult to match them to the Census data.

Comment: How are the clusters defined? In survey sampling, clusters or primary sampling units are sampled from a list of such units... so say if you had 80 communities and sampled 13 of them, that's a sample. If you had 13 geographies to begin with, and you had samples in each of them, these are strata rather than clusters. I am just trying to clarify/rectify the terms here.

Comment: please provide your responses as edits to your OP rather than as comments. Other people looking at this won't be able to fish out that information from replies; it needs to be upfront in the main text. (Just some of the cultural norms of the site.)

Comment: How do you get your Census tables? (FactFinder, through ArcGIS, through Census FTP website, in some other weird way) Technically speaking, tables like DP05 and S0501 apply to the whole population, while your survey population (I am guessing) is age 18+. It is infuriating for me as a survey statistician that Census produces very few tables that subset to that age group, but here we are. For that reason, I usually use microdata such as ipums.org. (And the `ipfraking` workflow is basically based upon computing `ctotal` matrices out of that data.)

Comment: Thanks for your replies, @Brady. I think you can more or less disregard the `Cluster_Wt` you created. What you really need though is the geography variable as a weighting variable, and the corresponding population counts. I am afraid you would need to go back to AFF, get the tabulations at the *tract* level, and aggregate up to your 13 target geographies (on your end).